# Haskell instance: how could this be some valid code?

Tags: haskell

While I was writing a small example of the Show instance, I had made an indentation error:

```hs
module Main where

data B= B0|B1 

instance Show B where
show B0="0"
show B1="1"


main=print B0
```

Where, clearly, the working code is:

```hs
module Main where

data B= B0|B1 

instance Show B where
    show B0="0"
    show B1="1"


main=print B0
```

I was expecting to get a compile error on the first one, but instead I could run it and it ended up in:

`example.hs: stack overflow`

Why does this code even compile?

Also, why is this a runtime error only (which, if stack is unconstrained, fills up your RAM) and not a compilation error?

Comment: You should get a warning because there's no implementation for `show` inside your instance, since it's empty.

Comment: The `show B0 = "0"`, is another function you defined with the same name `show`, but does not matter. You thus made an instance of `Show` without a definition for `show`, since `Show` has functions that default to calling each other, it will indeed end in a stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you did not indent `show`, it means this does not belong to the `instance` for `Show`, you program is thus equivalent to:

```
instance Show B where  -- ← no implementations

show B0 = "0"
show B1 = "1"
```

You here thus construct another function `show`, that has nothing to do with the `Show` typeclass, but simply has the same name.

`Show` defines three functions [**`showsPrec :: Show a => Int -> a -> String -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showsPrec), [**`show :: a -> String -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show), and [**`showList :: [a] -> String -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showList). `showsPrec` is often used since it has a precedence system to use parenthesis.

As a result `show` is impelemented in terms of `showsPrec` and `showsPrec` is implemented in terms of `show`:

> ```
> class  Show a  where
>     {-# MINIMAL showsPrec | show #-}
>     -- …
>     showsPrec :: Int
>               -> a
>               -> ShowS
>     -- …
>     show      :: a   -> String
>     -- …
>     showList  :: [a] -> ShowS
>
>     showsPrec _ x s = show x ++ s
>     show x          = shows x ""
>     showList ls   s = showList__ shows ls s
>
> -- …
> shows           :: (Show a) => a -> ShowS
> shows           =  showsPrec 0
> ```

It is thus sufficient to implement `showsPrec` or `show`, that is why there is a `{-# MINIMUM showsPrec | show #-}` pragma at the top of the type class.

If you do not implement any of the two, then the compiler will raise a warning, and use thus the basic implementations, but that will lead to nothing, since `show` will call `showPrec`, which will then call `show`, until eventually the stack is exhausted.

Answer (score 6):

The body of an `instance` can be empty.  You can leave out the `where` clause:

```
instance Show B
```

but you can also include it:

```
instance Show B where
-- nothing here
```

This can be useful for type classes that provide default implementations for the methods, perhaps based on generic programming facilities.  For example, with the `aeson` package, the usual way of defining instances to convert to and from JSON is to use generics and empty instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics

data Person = Person {
      name :: Text
    , age  :: Int
    } deriving (Generic, Show)

-- these empty instances use Generics to provide a default implementation
instance ToJSON Person
instance FromJSON Person
```

In your program, by leaving out the indentation, you've defined an `instance Show B` with no method definitions (and `-Wall` would generate a "missing method" warning telling you that it did not meet the minimal requirements for the instance).  The unindented `show` is providing a new top-level definition for `show`, unrelated to the `show` in the `Show` type class.

You haven't used `show` explicitly.  Instead, you've used it implicitly via `print`, which always calls the `show` from the type class, ignoring your top-level definition, so your crashing program is equivalent to:

```
data B = B0 | B1
instance Show B
main = print B0
```

This generates a stack overflow because there are default definitions of `show` and `showsPrec` that are used when no specific instances are given:

```
show x = shows x ""
showsPrec _ x s = show x ++ s
```

which operate together with the top-level function `shows` (not part of the type class):

```
shows = showsPrec 0
```

This works great when at least one of `show` or `showsPrec` is defined in the instance, and then the other gets a sensible definition, but if neither is defined, this creates an infinite recursive loop between these three functions.

Also, note that the following program would tell you `show` was ambiguous which would make it clearer what was going on.

```
module Main where

data B= B0|B1 

instance Show B where
show B0="0"
show B1="1"

main=putStrLn (show B0) -- instead of print
```

Comment: I didn't knew that the where clause could be empty! Is there a good reason to allow it as empty?

Comment: @Foxhole: some typeclasses have default implementations, and thus do not per se require an implementation.

Comment: @Foxhole If you leave the `where` clause empty, sometimes the compiler can write the definition for you if the typeclass author has defined default method implementations.

Comment: As per the comments, I've pointed to an example where empty instances are useful and also tried to explain more clearly why they lead to a stack overflow with `Show`.

Comment: Oops, I guess @WillemVanOnsem had already explained that...  anyway.

Comment: I haven't thought about default implementations, makes sense. Thanks for the great explanations @WillemVanOnsem